# Parallelize simple for loop

Tags: parallelization

I am trying the following code:

```
Stocks = FinancialData["DE:AA*", "Lookup"];
Prices = ConstantArray[0, Length[Stocks]];
Parallelize[For[i = 1, i <= Length[Stocks], i++,
Prices[[i]] = FinancialData[Stocks[[i]], "Jan. 1, 2000"]]]
```

Why does parallelize not work here? It should be straightforward to distribute the preallocated List to different cores. Or am I wrong?

Best,
Max

Edit:

I also tried the following to no avail:

```
Stocks = FinancialData["DE:AA*", "Lookup"];
Prices = {};
ParallelDo[
AppendTo[Prices, FinancialData[Stocks[[i]], "Jan. 1, 2000"]], {i, 
Length[Stocks]}]
```

Comment: What about `prices = ParallelMap[FinancialData[#, "Jan. 1, 2000"] &, 
  FinancialData["DE:AA*", "Lookup"]]`?

Answer (score 1):

Answer: The second approach works if I make Prices a shared Variable:

```
Stocks = FinancialData["DE:A*", "Lookup"];
Prices = {};
Length[Stocks]
SetSharedVariable[Prices]
SetSharedVariable[j]
Monitor[ParallelDo[j = i;
 AppendTo[Prices, FinancialData[Stocks[[i]], "Jan. 1, 2000"]], {i, 
  Length[Stocks]}], j]
```